# invoke a function within the object and save the result to another object

Tags: javascript

Can any one explain why TypeError: this.method2 is not a function. As I believe this is not may be the right way to do it.

```
var _obj = {

    method1: function() {
        console.log("this is form method 1");
    },
    method2: function() {
        this.method1();
    },

    start:this.method2()
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a simple mistake here, this is how you shoul do it:

```
var _obj = {

method1: function() {
     console.log("this is form method 1");
},
method2: function() {
     this.method1();
},

start: function(){
  this.method2()
 }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was wondering, if anyone can explain this please.